# Why does biblatex-chicago print accessed twice in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am using `biblatex-chicago` to manage my bibliography but whenever I try to set a bibliography entry with the `urldate` field, it prints the word 'accessed' twice.

I have created a minimal example to demonstrate the problem. My source document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[australian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\vfill\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And `temp.bib` looks like this:

```
@online{ key,
  author = "Surname, Forename M.",
  title = "Title of an article",
  year = "2012",
  url = "http://www.test.com/",
  urldate = "2012-04-18",
}
```

When I compile this, I end up with a reference list that looks like this:

```
Surname, Forename M. 2012. Title of an article. http://www.test.com/
    (accessed [accessed 18 Apr. 2012]).
```

Can anyone see what is going on? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How recently have you updated the `biblatex-chicago` package?

Comment: @lockstep: I'm using TeX Live 2011 on Windows, so the version that comes with that. My log includes the line `Package: biblatex-chicago 2011/08/31 v 1.6 biblatex style` if that helps.

Comment: That's a bug in biblatex-chicago, in the cbx-files. The definition of `url+date` prints the text twice. `\printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}}` should be either only `\printurldate` or `\printext[urldate]{\printfield{urlyear}...}`. Notify the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the `babel` is clashing with `biblatex-chicago`. Pass on the options `american` or `english` to babel like `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. According to `biblatex-chicago` documentation the option `australian` is not supported. (Refer section 6, page 95 to explore the possibilities of using `australian english` (if at all possible)). You need to have, it seems, the appropriate `australian.lbx` file (which is not supplied by `biblatex-chicago` by default) to get it working.

With `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, everything seems to work normally:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % changed the option to english
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{temp.bib}
%
\begin{document}
%
\cite{key}
%\vfill % commented to show things close by. 
\printbibliography
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part of the manual. It's a shame it doesn't support Australian or UK English, though.

Comment: OK, the easiest workaround seems to be to leave the option as `australian` and add the line `\DeclareLanguageMapping{australian}{cms-american}` afterwards. That way only `biblatex` is using American English - I still get British hyphenation for the main document.